# Sonarqube java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, linux, sonarqube

I have set up a SonarQube server and trying to run sonar scanner for PHP project but whenever I start the scanner I keep getting java heap size issues I did try to find out how to solve it but I can't find the solution anywhere.

Error is mention below

```
Exception in thread "Report about progress of PHP analyzer" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.sonar.squidbridge.ProgressReport.run(ProgressReport.java:62)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
17:48:59.134 DEBUG: eslint-bridge server will shutdown
17:48:59.571 DEBUG: stylelint-bridge server will shutdown
17:48:59.575 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:48:59.575 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
17:48:59.575 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:48:59.576 INFO: Total time: 10:45.620s
17:48:59.665 INFO: Final Memory: 14M/50M
17:48:59.666 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:48:59.666 ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.sonar.sslr.internal.matchers.ParseNode.<init>(ParseNode.java:39)
        at org.sonar.sslr.internal.vm.Machine.createNode(Machine.java:256)
        at org.sonar.sslr.internal.vm.Instruction$RetInstruction.execute(Instruction.java:305)
        at org.sonar.sslr.internal.vm.Machine.execute(Machine.java:162)
        at org.sonar.sslr.internal.vm.Machine.execute(Machine.java:105)
        at org.sonar.sslr.internal.vm.Machine.parse(Machine.java:83)
        at org.sonar.sslr.parser.ParseRunner.parse(ParseRunner.java:46)
        at com.sonar.sslr.api.typed.ActionParser.parse(ActionParser.java:101)
        at com.sonar.sslr.api.typed.ActionParser.parse(ActionParser.java:97)
        at org.sonar.php.parser.PHPParser.parse(PHPParser.java:53)
        at org.sonar.php.parser.PHPParser.parse(PHPParser.java:33)
        at org.sonar.php.PHPAnalyzer.nextFile(PHPAnalyzer.java:76)
        at org.sonar.plugins.php.PHPSensor.analyseFile(PHPSensor.java:172)
        at org.sonar.plugins.php.PHPSensor.analyseFiles(PHPSensor.java:147)
        at org.sonar.plugins.php.PHPSensor.execute(PHPSensor.java:122)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor$$Lambda$334/0x00000008006a0440.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:386)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:382)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:351)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:141)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
```

Please if anyone can help me with this.
Thank you

Comment: see: [How to solve Sonarqube java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381573/how-to-solve-sonarqube-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space)

Comment: I already did that but still having the same issue

Comment: Okay let me check with this value but i think that would also  not work cause i last time i did setup 2048m which didn't work

Comment: Having same issue like it was before:


11:40:31.532 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
11:40:31.532 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:40:31.536 INFO: Total time: 17:56.778s
11:40:31.659 INFO: Final Memory: 13M/50M
11:40:31.659 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:40:31.659 ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
`

Comment: I meant to say, you should try a value > than 512, so, when you tried `-Xmx2048m`, you can still try `-Xmx3000m` or `-Xmx4000m`, but you should not set it too high. I cannot test because I do not have your PHP project files....

Comment: Just wanted to know which JDK version you are using and which bit ? 32bit or 64bit

Comment: openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)